# batch parsing data after a character/text from a word file in powershell

Tags: powershell, indexing, split, ms-word

I am processing a batch of word documents.
I've successfully been able to extract the data that I wanted to a text file using this code:

```
$info = gci 'C:\Users\xxx\xxx'  -Recurse -File *.doc -Include *lol -Exclude *poo*) | ForEach-Object {
Get-Content ($_.fullName ) |  Where-Object {  $_.Contains("Date:")}
Get-Content ($_.fullName ) |  Where-Object {  $_.Contains("Name:")}
}
$info > C:\Users\xxx.txt
```

This creates a text file like this-
Date:  1/11/2011
Name   Joe Shmoe
For each found document...

I would like to remove the "Date:" and "Name:" part of the output for later extraction to an Excel file.

I've tried multiple methods using the `$name.Split(':')` followed by `$name2 = $name.Substring($name.IndexOf(':') +1)` and returning `$name2` Heck, I've tried a ton of things.  The best I could get was a complete iteration through each of the 100 files (with different names/dates) but only one name and date was returned 100 times.  Could someone please help me out with this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should accomplish your goal:

```
#Requires -Version 3

$Params = @{
    Path = 'C:\Users\xx\xx'
    Filter = '*.doc'
    Include = '*lol'
    Exclude = '*poo*'
    File = $True
    Recurse = $True
}
Get-ChildItem @Params |
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName |
            Where-Object { $_ -match '(date)|(name):' }) -replace '(date)|(name):'
    } |
    Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Users\xxx.txt'
```

Comment: Great! Using `Where-Object {$_ -match 'Date:'} -replace 'Date:'` did the trick.  Thank you!